# AxonIQ AxonFramework MongoEventStorageEngine framework table creation on business DB

Tags: spring-boot, cqrs, axon, saga, axon-framework

I am using AxonIQ AxonFramework version `4.5.3` with Spring Boot and custom event store.

I'm using `MongoEventStorageEngine` and configured a separate MongoDB database for the `EventStorage`.

I am doing some business logic with my business database through a microservice. In the same microservice, I've configured the custom EventStorage.

But a few tables (viz. **association_value_entry, saga_entry, token_entry**) are getting created on my business database which is a PostgresDB.

Why is AxonFramework creating new tables in my business database as I have already configured a separate MongoDB database for EventStorage. All the related database objects for Axon to work should be ideally created in the EventStorage database rather than in my business database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The tables you are mentioned should be part of your 'read' model (I believe that is what you called `business database`).
They are not used for Event Storage or Event Sourcing but rather to specific things that are controlled on client side. For example, `token_entry`, among other things, is the table where your app keep track of the tokens and events it already consumed - you can read more about it [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#token-store). Similar to the saga tables, where Sagas are stored on the client side having nothing to do with the Event Store - you can read more about it [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas/implementation#saga-infrastructure).

Comment: Fine, but why is it touching the business database? It would be better if Axon change the logic and use the configured EventStorage for these. It should be like "you have been given a locker, store everything in that locker than using someone else's locker"

Comment: That is not how it works... those tables are to be accessed by Axon Framework (the client app) and they have nothing to do with Event Storage. That is part of the Framework and not Axon Server, meaning they will be there no matter if you are using Axon Server or not.

Comment: I was trying out a simple ecart project, and I see Axon framework is creating the above tables in the Product, Order etc databases. In production, we will not have the privilege to create any tables in these databases. So is there any way out to use Axon framework without creating these tables in the databases. I'm not using Axon server only client side Axon Framework is being used.